# `\eqdef` in kpfonts with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, kpfonts

#### Question

**How to get the `\eqdef` symbol working with `kpfonts` in xelatex?**

##### Details

`kpfonts` does *not* provide the `\eqdef` symbol, which is a small text "def" set over equals sign. (≝ (U+225D)) In pdftex, I fake it by oversetting those three letters `\overset{\mbox{\tiny def}}{=}`. So far so good.

But if I compile the same file using xetex, it doesn't work. (The `kpfonts` package automatically detects xetex engine and loads `kpfonts-otf` instead.)

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\newcommand\eqdef{\overset{\mbox{\tiny def}}{=}}

\begin{document}
$\eqdef$
\end{document}
```

Building with `xelatex`, the output shows:

```
Missing character: There is no ≝ (U+225D) in font [KpMath-Regular.otf]/OT:scrip
t=math;language=dflt;!
[1] (./testkp.aux) )
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 3 was incomplete)
```

It seems that `unicode-math` (which is loaded by `kpfonts-otf`) is silently overwriting the definition of `\eqdef` that I provided, but then fails to actually find the unicode symbol in the font.

**What is the correct way to solve this?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple-minded solution: redefine the command after `unicode-math` sets it up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand \eqdef{\ensuremath{\mathrel{\overset{\mbox{\tiny def}}{=}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
$\eqdef$
\end{document}
```

Whether this is 'the correct way' to solve the problem is really a function of whether your original definition of `\eqdef` for pdfLaTeX was the correct way to solve it there. If you check the definition of `\eqdef` before rewriting it, `unicode-math` isn't setting up anything fancy. It's just assigning the (non-existent) character,

```
> \eqdef=the character ≝.
```

One issue might be scaling. Whereas `≝` and `=` will scale, `\tiny def` will not. So if this was something you needed in different sizes, the redefinition wouldn't be sufficient. But, in that case, the original definition wouldn't be sufficient for pdfLaTeX either.

If your question is about redefining `\eqdef` at all, this approach is straight out of `unicode-math`'s own documentation (page 23),

> 6.2 How to overwrite a macro `unicode-math` defines the macros by `\AtBeginDocument`, namely delays the definition until `\begin{document}` is met. If you want to overwrite a macro defined by `unicode-math`, please redefine it in `\AtBeginDocument` after loading this package.

Moreover, there's no straightforward way to prevent `unicode-math` from defining commands for missing characters. The basic format is just

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"0225D}{\eqdef                    }{\mathrel}{equals by definition}%
```

So you would need to redefine `\UnicodeMathSymbol` to check. But, first, this is not the expected behaviour and, second, it would be fraught with difficulties.

For the first point, it is entirely standard for LaTeX itself and packages to define commands for characters which are missing from the fonts used. This results in the familiar warning in the log. If the commands were not defined, users would otherwise get errors about undefined commands. While these errors would, strictly speaking, be accurate, they would not be as informative as warnings about specific missing characters.

Regarding the second, it would be problematic to assume that the current font at the time of definition will be the current font at the time of use. This would risk creating the worst of both worlds: missing commands for extant characters and extant commands for missing characters. `unicode-math` defers definitions until the beginning of the document, when maths fonts should hopefully have been configured, but a user could decide to change them later.

Comment: Ok. Mainly asking in case there is a way to tell `unicode-math` not to do any (re)definitions that would result in non-existent symbols being called.

Comment: @WillieWong This method is straight out of `unicode-math`'s manual. See edit and page 23 section 6.2. This is how you're meant to do it if you need a different definition. It's also a very standard way of doing this type of thing in LaTeX. Lots of font configuration relies on this basic mechanism and it has the advantage of ensuring people's documents don't fail to compile if they switch fonts. (Maybe that's a disadvantage, but it's a long-standing behaviour.)

Comment: @WillieWong See edit.

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround could be to borrow the missing glyphs from another Math font, for instance:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}[range={"2258-"225B,"225D-"225F}]
\begin{document}
\[A\eqdef B, A=B\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The suggested range covers the "equations like" glyphs missing in the `kpfonts` (legacy and OpenType).

Another choice could be the TeX-Gyre Paladio font (also Palatino like), you would get

[image]

setting:

`\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}[range={"2258-"225B,"225D-"225F}, Scale=0.8]`